# Object particle flicker and halted dynamics

Tags: rendering, animation, particles, collision

I have an object particle system that seems to work fine in the OpenGL preview animation, but the final render causes flickering and the dynamics suddenly stop. Here's a video showing the final render and the OpenGL preview right after it: https://vid.me/bUVq.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll admit I'm not entirely sure why, but the issue seems to stem from the particles colliding with the plane at the bottom. If the object isn't closed so that all normals are facing outward, then the particles which get stuck in the collider cause flickering and the dynamics fail.

So, the solution to this problem is to add a solidify modifier to the plane collider at the bottom. To illustrate the difference before and after the adding the solidify modifier to the plane, I'll show you scaled down versions of frames 80 and 85.

[image: Frame 80 Before]
[image: Frame 85 Before]

As you can see above, the petals just seem to fall down with very minor rotation. If I were to render more frames, you'd see that some petals flicker in and out. This is definitely not desired.

[image: Frame 80 After]
[image: Frame 85 After]

And now you can see that the scene is completely changed now that there is no error. All the petals seem to rotate or translate to a different position.